# Mastermind puzzle - 6 rows each with one correct and one misplaced

Tags: logical-deduction, mastermind

Here is a relatively easy mastermind puzzle that I came up with a while ago, the aim is to find the hidden code like as if you were playing normally (you should not have to guess, there is more than enough information already)
[image: Mastermind puzzle].

Here is a text version:

```
guess C M

SWBO  1 1
PRSY  1 1
GYRB  1 1
YPWO  1 1
OBGS  1 1
PRWG  1 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

> Pink, Blue, Red, Orange

Found it by:

> Drew out a crude list of what colors were on what lines, then selected the four colors that only had two of the chosen on each line. Then, I took down the position of each peg on the respective line, and selected the only combination that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I found an error in your puzzle.

You said, *"You can take out any two (rows) and the puzzle is still solvable."*

> That's not correct.  If you take out the two middle rows, you are left with this:
>
>  guess C M
>  ----- ---
>  SWBO  1 1
>
>  PRSY  1 1
>
>  OBGS  1 1
>
>  PRWG  1 1

And with these four rows, there is not one but TWO solutions:

> (1) Pink, Blue, Red, Orange
>
>  (2) Orange, Red, Blue, Pink

(I wrote a computer program that plays Mastermind, generates Mastermind puzzles, and solves Mastermind Puzzles.  This Mastermind program I wrote found the alternate solution, not me.)

Ed Collins

Comment: Hello and welcome to PSE. Please hide your answers in spoilers!